Tracking error, formula from one month to one year
Tracking error defined as this one:
https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/trackingerror.asp
What is the formula for going from 1 month to 1 year?

The monthly tracking error $STDEV(X_i-B_i)$ could be annualized by multiplying by $\sqrt{12}$, the square root of the number of months in 1 year.
